# How to Connect a tf::messageFilter to two subscribers

Tags: message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I would like to synchronise two sensor inputs with a tf::messageFilter. How would I go about connecting both message_filters::subscribers to a single tf::messageFilter.

I have tried to sync both the subscribers via a synchroniser using an approximate time policy. I would like to connect this to the tf::messageFilter
In the header file I have:

```
tf::TransformListener m_tfListener;
    typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix, sensor_msgs::Imu> MySyncPolicy;
    message_filters::Subscriber< sensor_msgs::NavSatFix > *m_gpsSub;
    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Imu> *m_imuSub;
    message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy>* sync;

    tf::MessageFilter< sensor_msgs::NavSatFix, sensor_msgs::Imu>* m_gpsFilter;
```

in the .cpp file I have

```
 m_gpsSub= new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>(private_nh, "fix", 5);
  m_imuSub = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Imu>(private_nh, "imu", 5) 
  m_gpsFilter = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix, sensor_msgs::Imu>(m_tfListener, odomFrameId, 10) 
  sync= new message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy>(MySyncPolicy(20), *m_gpsSub, *m_imuSub);
  m_gpsFilter->connectInput(sync);
  m_gpsFilter->registerCallback(boost::bind(&SwarmbotMCL::gpsCallback, this, _1, _2));
```

however It complains that tf::MessageFilter can only take one input:

```
 error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
/opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/message_filter.h:106:7: error: provided for ‘template<class M> class tf::MessageFilter’
```

does anyone know of the correct way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193120/how-to-connect-a-tf::messagefilter-to-two-subscribers/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2014-09-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the insight given in a previous answer that this is possible because the tf::message_filter is just another message filter, I came up with the following working solution. Sync your tf::message_filter with one (or possibly both) your message_filter subscribers. pass the pointer of the resulting tf::message_filter to your synchronizer, and link you synchronizer to the callback. As in the following reworked .cpp code :

```
m_gpsSub= new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>(private_nh, "fix", 5);

  m_imuSub = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Imu>(private_nh, "imu", 5);
  //m_gpsSub->connectInput(m_imuSub);
  m_gpsFilter = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>(*m_gpsSub, m_tfListener, odomFrameId, 10);

  sync= new message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy>(MySyncPolicy(20), *m_gpsFilter,  *m_imuSub );
  //m_gpsFilter->connectInput(sync);
  sync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&SwarmbotMCL::gpsCallback, this, _1, _2));
```

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2014-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkuwenjian](https://answers.ros.org/users/52110/nkuwenjian/) on 2020-03-21**:
Thanks very much! It works!